# Where can I find good filigree?

Tags: resource-recommendations, font-recommendation

I don't have the skills necessary to create filigree elements myself.

Where can I find some pre-existing ones (preferably vectors or fonts)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Vectors

- [iStockphoto "filigree" illustration search](http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/filigree/filetypes/%1337%135/source/basic/?) (commercial, royalty free)
- [Vectorstock "filigree"](http://www.vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vectors/keyword/filigree) (commercial, royalty free)
- [Shutterstock "filigree" vector search](http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?lang=en&search_source=search_form&similar_photo_id=&searchterm=filigree&anyorall=all&search_cat=29&people_gender=&people_age=&people_ethnicity=&people_number=&search_group=all&orient=all&photographer_name=&searchtermx=&safesearch=1&color=) (commercial, royalty free)
- [GraphicRiver "filigree"](http://graphicriver.net/searches?term=filigree&type=files) (commercial, royalty free)
- [Dreamstime "filigree" search](http://www.dreamstime.com/search.php?s_il=y&s_ad=y&s_rf=y&s_ed=y&srh_field=filigree+&firstvalue=filigree+&lastsearchvalue=null&s_sm=all&s_st=new&memso=y&s_cf=0&s_catid=&s_cliid=&s_colid=&memorize_search=1&s_exc=&s_excp=&s_sp=&s_sl1=y&s_sl2=y&s_sl3=y&s_sl4=y&s_sl5=y&s_color1=FFFFFF&s_percent1=10&s_color2=FFFFFF&s_percent2=10&s_rsf=0&s_rst=7&s_clc=y&s_clm=y&s_orp=y&s_ors=y&s_orl=y&s_orw=y&referrer=1484412) (commercial, royalty free)
- [Fotolio filigree search](http://us.fotolia.com/search?k=filigree&order=relevance&filters%5bcollection%5d=all&filters%5bcontent_type%3Avector%5d=1&filters%5borientation%5d=all&with_offensive=on&without_offensive=on&limit=32&search.x=12&search.y=10&partner=201103219) (commercial, royalty free)
- [Bigstockphoto filigree search](http://www.bigstockphoto.com/search/?q%5bst%5d=filigree&q%5bcolor%5d=&q%5bsi%5d=hot&q%5bcat%5d%5bmain%5d=&q%5bill%5d=any&q%5buid%5d=&q%5bori%5d=&q%5bfmt%5d=vector&q%5brel%5d=Both&q%5badl%5d=n&q%5bpm%5d=show&q%5blp%5d=Any&refid=D9fk3hvJXb) (commercial, royalty free)

### Fonts

- [dafont "shapes" dingbats](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=710) (different licenses)
- [myFonts "ornament" tag](http://new.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Aornament/fonts/) (different licenses)

Answer (score 2):

deviantart.com often has a wide variety of non-commercial design elements, or just spend some time with google and you will probably come up with something!